# Heat kernel asymptotic expansion on complete noncompact manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, asymptotics, heat-equation

I was wondering if there is any reference for the asymptotic expansion of heat kernel on a complete noncompact manifold. That is,

\begin{align}
H(x,q,t) \sim \frac1{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{d^2(q,x)}{4t}}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}t^j u_j(x,t)
\end{align}
for any $x$ in a compact set and $t$ small. Here the expansion means
\begin{align} 
H(x,q,t) - \frac1{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{d^2(q,x)}{4t}}\sum_{j=0}^kt^j u_j(x,t)=O(t^{k+1-n/2}).
\end{align}

Comment: Do you assume your manifold to be of bounded geometry? If yes, I would say that the answer is yes, it comes out from how a heat kernel on a manifold can be constructed, and the keyword is "parametrix" (see a reference to Candel-Conlon in this answer — https://mathoverflow.net/questions/197892/alternative-proof-of-varadhans-formula-on-riemann-manifolds/197978#197978 )

Answer (score 2):

The only reference I can offer you is the work by Vassilevich; [Heat Kernel Expansion: User’s Manual](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0306138.pdf)

The chapter on *Non-Integrable potentials* may be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES:

- Kannai, Y. *Off diagonal short time asymptotics for fundamental solutions of diffusion equations*. Comm. Partial Differential Equations 2 (1977), no. 8, 781–830, https://doi.org/10.1080/03605307708820048